# How to create tasks to repeat at a certain time in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

After some research I read in several places that Apple does not let applications run in backgroud except for some specific categories, but I need a solution and I could not find help in any documentation and / or research.

I have the need to leave an automatic task to occur at 10:45 pm which in the case would be to subtract the existing value in a variable to another variable, a discount calculation basically, however the user can choose which days of the week it will repeat itself , however the schedule it runs will always be at 10:45 pm, would anyone have a solution?

Comment: You can't execute code at a specific time, but it doesn't sound like you need to anyway.  All you need to do is when the application is launched determine the new value based on the current time

Comment: Thanks, how does this update work when the application starts? and how could you tell if two days had passed that should have been updated?

Comment: Just store the date you last updated in user defaults and thenwhen thenapp launches or returns to the foreground you can compare that against the date now and perform the calculations

Comment: How would you do that? I do not know in what method I enter this, how can I check the current date and the Apple documentation also says nothing about it

Comment: Look at the methods in your `AppDelegate` `willEnterForeground` `didEnterBackground` and `didFinishLaunching`. You can create a `Date` object to get the current date and time